# Multiple strings containing duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am required to do the following :

> The Address should be concatenated into a lower case string with no
>   spaces and then compared against the other address.

I have the below sql - with no schema this will be hard to answer but I really just want to know how I can add in the part to concat the address into lower case with no spaces and then compare against other addresses.

I have the following fields along with what's already in the SQL below: Address1, Address2, Address3, Town, Postcode.

```
;With dups as (
 select distinct p.GtId
 from CORE.WeccoParty p
 join CORE.WeccoPartyAddress a ON p.GtId = a.GtId

 where exists (select 1
           from CORE.WeccoParty sub_p
           left join CORE.WeccoPartyAddress sub_a 
             on sub_p.GtId = sub_a.GtId and sub_a.AddressType = 'Mailing'
           where (p.FirstName     =  sub_p.FirstName
                  and p.LastName  =  sub_p.LastName
                  and p.Dob       =  sub_p.Dob
                  and p.GtId      <> sub_p.GtId)
                  and a.MailingAddress =  sub_a.MailingAddress
                  and a.GtId           <> sub_a.GtId
              ) 
)
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: `REPLACE(LOWER(CONCAT(Addr1, Addr2, Addr3)),' ','') = {Other Column}`? Too little information here.

Comment: Is WeccoPartyAddress.MailingAddress only address field or do you have any other field?

Comment: That left join returns regular inner join result. (Move sub_a conditions from WHERE to ON to get true left join result. But perhaps you want an inner join?)

Comment: Updated Question to include other fields